Merging two dictionaries in JSON
I have two JSON files:
file1.json:
{
    "tables": {
        "table_a": {
            "tags": [],
            "schema": "x",
            "source": "internet",
            "description": ""
        },
        "table_b": {
            "tags": [],
            "schema": "x",
            "source": "internet",
            "description": ""
        },
        "table_c": {
            "tags": [],
            "schema": "x",
            "source": "internet",
            "description": ""
        }
    },
    "created_at": 1712648683040,
    "updated_at": 1712648683040
}


file2.json:
{
    "tables": {
        "table_a": {
            "tags": [],
            "schema": "y",
            "source": "internet",
            "description": ""
        },
        "table_b": {
            "tags": [],
            "schema": "y",
            "source": "internet",
            "description": ""
        }
    },
    "created_at": 1712648683040,
    "updated_at": 1712648683040
}


the result that I want:
{
    "tables": {
        "table_a": {
            "tags": [],
            "schema": "x",
            "source": "internet",
            "description": ""
        },
        "table_b": {
            "tags": [],
            "schema": "x",
            "source": "internet",
            "description": ""
        },
        "table_c": {
            "tags": [],
            "schema": "x",
            "source": "internet",
            "description": ""
        },
        "table_a": {
            "tags": [],
            "schema": "y",
            "source": "internet",
            "description": ""
        },
        "table_b": {
            "tags": [],
            "schema": "y",
            "source": "internet",
            "description": ""
        }
    },
    "created_at": 1712648683040,
    "updated_at": 1712648683040
}

Basically I want to have duplicate tables even if they have the same name they have different schemas.
What I've tried so far:
def merge_data(file1_data, file1_data):
    merged_tables = {}
    for table_name, table_info in file1_data['tables'].items():
        merged_tables[table_name] = table_info

    for table_name, table_info in file1_data['tables'].items():
        merged_tables[table_name] = table_info

    merged_tables_list = [{table_name: table_info} for table_name, table_info in merged_tables.items()]

    merged_data = {
        "tables": merged_tables_list,
        "created_at": file1_data["created_at"],
        "updated_at": file1_data["updated_at"]
    }

    return merged_data

Problem is that this will override the duplicate tables, can I append somehow?
edit: result doesn't need to be sorted by schema or anything
